# Java - method argument for any instance extending a given object

Tags: java, object, inheritance, methods, parameters

Since I don't know how to phrase my question so that I get a helping result just by searching via Google I decided to ask here. I'm just searching for a way to tell a method that it should take every Object extending a certain class. Here are the things I tried so far:

```
public void method( Object<? extends Component> obj );

public void method( Component c );
```

The problem with the second one is that i have to cast every instance to Component again before method() accepts it and the first one just didn't work for me. Can anyone give me a quick solution?

Comment: It is very strange that you need to cast your classes to Component before calling the method. This should not be the case. Can you provide the piece of code that requires a cast? Chances are you have some other problem there.

Comment: what do you mean exactly tell method to extend a certain class?

Comment: IEntity e = es.createEntity();
e.addComponent((Component)new Position( x, y, z ));

There you go...

Comment: `Object<? extends Component>` doesn't make sense

Comment: you shouldn't have to cast `Position` to `Component` if `Position` extends `Component`.

Comment: `Object` is not a generic type, hence why your first solution won't work. Your second solution should just work and will accept any Components or sub-types of Component.

Comment: Suddenly, it's working! I don't know why it didn't earlier, I'm sorry for the trouble then.

Answer (score 6):

> The problem with the second one is that i have to cast every instance
>   to Component again before method() accepts it

No, you don't have to cast anything, that's how polymorphism works.

For example:

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends B {
}

public class Main {

    private void method(final A a) {
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Main main = new Main();
        main.method(new B());
        main.method(new C());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to define a method that takes subtypes of Component, use `public <T extends Component>  void method(T t){your code here}`. This will work for any object, i.e. Component can be replaced with any other class that has subclasses.

Comment: This is not usually needed. Why not define the parameter as Component?

Comment: "I'm just searching for a way to tell a method that it should take every Object extending a certain class." I was under the impression you wanted to use "extends" in your method def, but yes, simple "Component" will work for the parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

The second form `public void method( Component c );` is correct, If you need to typecast then you are trying to pass as parameter a variable which type is not Component or a subclass of Component. I don't know why.

Declaring variables with type Object is not usually the right thing to do, you should define them with the correct type when you know it.

Typecast is the way to tell the compiler you know the type of the object pointed by a reference when that reference does not have that type for any reason.